# How to pivot data in SQL with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am working on a data where it looks like this

[image]

I want to pivot it in this way :

[image]

I have written in this way :

```
select * 
  from (select * FROM records) as test
  PIVOT (
  max(value) for
  [Question_ID] in ((SELECT distinct [Question_ID] from records order by 1))) AS PivotTable
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also post the sample data in `text` format not as an image

Comment: *a data where it looks like this* Replace with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And specify DBMS, including its version.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy - Sql Server

Comment: @Akina - I am new to SQL, aware of ddl and dml and using MSSMS

Comment: SSMS may generate table's DDL and table's data DML - use.

Comment: @ViswaranjanNarendrasingh, If the answers provided below solved your problem, accept the answer or at least an upvote. Check this [How do I accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

you got your wish result

```
    select * 
  from (select * FROM #temp) as test--your table name replace with #temp
  PIVOT (
  max(value) for
  [Question_ID] in ([120],[122],[149],[150],[151],[189],[253],[554],[774] )) AS PivotTable
```

or if you want to dynamic your query

```
  DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Question_ID) 
            FROM #temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        --print @cols
set @query = 'SELECT ID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select ID
                    , Question_ID
                    , [Value]
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max([Value])
                for [Question_ID] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table #temp


----------
```

Comment: I tried with the same and I got the output but I want to automate the Question id as there are hundreds of question id

Comment: you want dynamic ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of columns in `PIVOT`, you can directly hardcode like below.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM test
) t
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) for
  [Question_ID] in ([120],[122],[149],[150],[151],[189],[253],[554],[774] )) AS Pivot_Table
```

If not,you have to use `Dynamic Pivot table` for unknown number of column values.

```
DECLARE 
    @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '', 
    @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- select the QuestionIDs
SELECT 
    @columns+=QUOTENAME(Question_ID) + ','
FROM 
    test
GROUP BY Question_ID
ORDER BY Question_ID;

-- remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

-- construct dynamic SQL
SET @sql ='
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT * FROM TEST
) t 
PIVOT(
     MAX(value) for 
     [Question_ID] IN ('+ @columns +')
) AS pivot_table;';

-- execute the dynamic SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql;
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ce1d49ff8e2514261a286c22086c2db6)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the number of columns will not change, then you can use case statement

```
CREATE TABLE #TBL (ID INT, Question_ID INT, [Value] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO #TBL VALUES
(1,149,'abc'),(1,150,'def'),(1,151,'aff'),(1,122,'www'),
(2,120,'add'),(2,150,'sub'),(2,189,'asf'),(3,253,'asd'),
(3,150,'gfre'),(3,554,'cvew'),(3,744,'qwert')
-- aNSWER
SELECT
        ID,
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 149 THEN [Value] END) AS '149',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 150 THEN [Value] END) AS '150',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 151 THEN [Value] END) AS  '151',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 122 THEN [Value] END) AS '122',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 120 THEN [Value] END) AS '120',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 150 THEN [Value] END) AS '150',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 189 THEN [Value] END) AS '189',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 253 THEN [Value] END) AS '253',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 150 THEN [Value] END) AS '150',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 554 THEN [Value] END) AS '554',
         MAX(CASE WHEN Question_ID = 744 THEN [Value] END) AS '744'             
FROM #TBL
        GROUP BY ID
DROP TABLE #TBL
```

Output

```
ID  149   150   151  122    120   150   189   253   150   554   744
1   abc   def   aff  www    NULL  def   NULL  NULL  def   NULL  NULL
2   NULL  sub   NULL NULL   add   sub   asf   NULL  sub   NULL  NULL
3   NULL  gfre  NULL NULL   NULL  gfre  NULL  asd   gfre  cvew  qwert
```